# What is a portable way to check if a SERIAL/COM port is in use in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am working with a Java framework and I need to check for serial COM ports that are free (not opened by any other applications).  Is it possible to check this in Java?  One caveat is that I cannot add any packages to the application, I must only use standard Java classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: On *nix systems the serial port is bound into the filesystem (e.g. /dev/ttyS0). Maybe the java.io can be used to access that "files" and get some exceptions, if the port is already open ...

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer it be platform independent if possible.  I don't think it is possible but I thought I would ask here to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This works using JDK 1.6.0_21 and `javax.comm` is by Sun/Oracle but I don't know if it meets you definition of being a standard java class as its a separate install.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;


public class PortList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enumeration<?> ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    StringBuffer buffer =  new StringBuffer("Ports:\n");
    while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
      CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
      String type;
      switch (port.getPortType()) {
      case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
        type = "Parallel";
        break;
      case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
        type = "Serial";
        break;
      default: /// Shouldn't happen
        type = "Unknown";
        break;
      }
      buffer.append(String.format("%s : %s Owner: %s\n",port.getName(),type,port.getCurrentOwner()));

    }
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
  }
}
```

The key method/class is  `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()`

Comment: The original Sun/Oracle implementation is outdated. You should use this http://rxtx.qbang.org .